# How to Replace pydantic.json.ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId] = str in Pydantic 2.x.x and FastAPI 1.x.x Versions?

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, bson, pydantic-v2

After Pydantic's migration to a new core, they have removed the usage of `pydantic.json.ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId] = str`. Despite all my attempts and research, I haven't been able to find what to replace it with.

I wanted to serialize ObjectId using native FastAPI methods, but this approach doesn't seem to work in the new versions.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to import this instead
`from pydantic.v1.json import ENCODERS_BY_TYPE`

then continue with your code `ENCODERS_BY_TYPE[ObjectId] = str`